# jQuery - show or hide table rows depending on background colors determined from multiple checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating one Asp.net application in which on one view page I have four checkboxes

[image].

On click checkbox table will be shown. If I will click on All then All rows will be shown. If I click on any colour like red, green or yellow the respective coloured rows filled with the colour will be displayed.

I want to select multiple colour rows at same time, but code is written and working only for one colour at a time.

For each checkbox select I have written separate jquery function but when I am selecting two check boxes only one colour row showing.

How to implement multiple selection of coloured rows in table?

Following is HTML/JS code:

`#DivTblIssueStatus` is the id of the table to be displayed.

```
For Yellow coloured rows function written:
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Yellow").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

      $("#DivTblIssueStatus").show();
      
            if (($('#TdPrgMgmt_Status')[0].style.backgroundColor) == 
     "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
                $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').show();
                $('#spnProgramStatus').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').hide();
                //$('#spnProgramStatus').show();
            }

    } else {
      $("#DivTblIssueStatus").hide();

    }
  });
});
```

```html
 For Red coloured function is written:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#Red").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            
            $("#DivTblIssueStatus").show();


            if (($('#TdPrgMgmt_Status')[0].style.backgroundColor) == 
 "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
                $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').show();
                $('#spnProgramStatus').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').hide();
                //$('#spnProgramStatus').show();
            }
});
});
</script>


 For green coloured rows code written:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#Green").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        
        $("#DivTblIssueStatus").show();


        if (($('#TdPrgMgmt_Status')[0].style.backgroundColor) == "rgb(0, 128, 
      0)") {
            $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').show();
            $('#spnProgramStatus').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').hide();
            //$('#spnProgramStatus').show();
        }
});
});
</script>

  Html Code: 

   <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<div id="ToIssueStatusColorFilter">

  <form>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="All">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="All" 
  value="All">All
                            </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Red">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Red" 
  value="Red">Red(R)
                            </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Green">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Green" 
 value="Green">Green(G)
                            </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Yellow">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Yellow" 
value="Yellow">Yellow(Y)
                            </label>
  </form>
  </div>
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iUwL.jpg)

Comment: provide your js code as well

Comment: Better yet, please use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in a page) and create a working example that demonstrates the issue. Also, I'm not seeing how this relates to ASP.NET MVC... if it doesn't please do remove that tag.

Comment: what are the rows here? we can solve only if you provide proper data only

Comment: Rows are the table rows which filled with colour.

Comment: Code is too much lengthy thats why i have not added the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add same css class to your checkboxes and then attach click event using css class selector, not ID. 
Then you check the ID or the value of each checkbox. You can store your color scheme in object, and then use the value of checkbox as key to extract the exact color in RGB value, compare it with targeted container's background color.

```js
var selectedColors = []; //here you pack your array of selected colors
var colorsScheme = {'Red': 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'Yellow' : 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', 'Green' : 'rgb(0, 128, 0)'};
//var colorsScheme = {'rgb(255, 0, 0)': 'Red', 'rgb(255, 255, 0)' : 'Yellow', 'rgb(0, 128, 0)' : 'Green'};
$(function () {

    $(".color-checkbox").click(function () {
        var selectedColor = $(this).val();
        if( selectedColor === 'All'){
            $(".color-checkbox").not(this).prop('checked', this.checked); //it will check or uncheck all other checkboxes, depending on All checkbox state
        }
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {


            //code for color selection
            //colors check
            if( selectedColor !== 'All'){

                if ($('#TdPrgMgmt_Status').css('background-color') === colorsScheme[selectedColor]) { //we use fully jQuery, to be consistent

                    $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').show();
                    $('#spnProgramStatus').hide();
                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            //do something, check colors

            $('#ProgramMgntstatus1').hide();

        }

        repopulateColorValues(); //at the end of callback, repopulate list of all selected colors

    });


});

function repopulateColorValues(){
    selectedColors = [];
    $(".color-checkbox").each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            if($(this).val() !== 'All'){ //skip the All value, we need only colors
                selectedColors.push(colorsScheme[$(this).val()]);
            }
        }
    });
    $('table#tableID tr.trClass').each(function(){ //iterate through table rows and check if row has color that is selected
        if (selectedColors.indexOf($(this).css('background-color')) !== -1) {
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
   // console.log(selectedColors); //just for debugging, do whatever you want with selectedColors
}
```

```css
#TdPrgMgmt_Status{
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ToIssueStatusColorFilter">
    <form>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="All">
            <input class="color-checkbox" name="color[]" type="checkbox" id="All" value="All">All
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Red">
            <input class="color-checkbox"  name="color[]" type="checkbox" id="Red" value="Red">Red(R)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Green">
            <input class="color-checkbox"   name="color[]" type="checkbox" id="Green" value="Green">Green(G)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Yellow">
            <input class="color-checkbox"  name="color[]" type="checkbox" id="Yellow" value="Yellow">Yellow(Y)
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="TdPrgMgmt_Status">
  Some Red Status 
</div>
<div id="ProgramMgntstatus1">
  #ProgramMgntstatus1
</div>
 <div id="spnProgramStatus">
   #spnProgramStatus
 </div>
 
 <table id="tableID">
   <tr class="trClass">
     <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:red;">
     <td>1. Red row </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:yellow;">
     <td>2. Yellow row</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:green;">
     <td>3. Green Row</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:yellow;">
     <td>4. Yellow row</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:yellow;">
     <td>5. Yellow row</td>
   </tr>
    <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:green;">
     <td>6. Green Row</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:red;">
     <td>7. Red row </td>
   </tr>
      <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:red;">
     <td>8. Red row </td>
   </tr>
      <tr class="trClass" style="background-color:green;">
     <td>9. Green Row</td>
   </tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: Hi
I have added the code for every colour, whenever I am selecting red colour red row will be displayed. As soon as I am clicking on yellow checkbox yellow rows get displayed, And red will not. If I am selecting two colors then both rows will be display

Comment: @Ruchita, please check my updated code. No need to treat each checkbox separately. Tend to reuse the code whenever you can.

Comment: Okay I will check n implement.

Comment: @Ruchita, I am now looking at your issue again. You should construct your question better next time. You want to show/hide all rows depending on color?

Comment: Yes I want to show and hide rows depends on colours.

Comment: @Ruchita, I have adjusted code, and it should work with table rows now

Comment: I have implemented the code on e thing I want to tell I have multiple table having coloured rows so that the implemented code is working same as my previous code(One color is shown at a time)

Comment: @Ruchita, than you have implemented that code as it shouldn't. Please run code snippet from my example, and you will see that it is working.

Comment: for me this 'if (selectedColors.indexOf($(this).css('background-color')) !== -1)' condition is not working it is going in else part and hiding table

Comment: I am setting the background colours to the rows dynamically through coding only.

Comment: @Ruchita, dude, just post the sample of your tables output then. You can't expect someone to help you if you don't have enough information. My sample code is working fine. The other thing is that you haven't provided other info.

Comment: Thanks @niklaz your code is working.
I have added output image for one table

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u953kt0e/33/
...Hi @niklaz....Thanks for you feedback... this is the code snippet you have given...I have made some changes ..Now I am iterating over td....and if condition is suucessful I want to display complete row now its showing only perticular colured column